# Pivot Queries in a UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server

Pivon queries, love em. Turn rows into columns. I need to do a pivot query on the union of 3 other queries. How do I structure this?

I already know the names of the fields in the rows I want to transform but where do I put the pivot statement so it works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a derived table:

```
SELECT ...
 FROM (
   SELECT ...
    FROM ...
   UNION ALL
   SELECT ...
    FROM ...
   ...)
PIVOT ...
```

or a CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT ...
    FROM ...
   UNION ALL
   SELECT ...
    FROM ...
   ...)
SELECT ...
  FROM cte
  PIVOT ...
```